# connect desktop to laptop using modem ubuntu

Tags: wireless, laptop, connection

i have a modem which has lan cable connected to my desktop for internet
and wifi connection  which i connect to laptop for internet usage

so now i can i connect laptop and desktop to each other so i can transfer files between them

i have this modem
[my modem](http://www.calcutta.bsnl.co.in/dataoneinstall/mu12.html)

both desktop and laptop os are ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure both your desktop and the laptop are on the same subnet.
2. Right-click on a folder and add sharing option. (It may prompt you to install Samba and restart the computer if necessary.)
3. Next, open Nautilus and type `smb://192.168.x.x` (replace x.x. with actual IP address of whichever computer you want to access. (The directories you have shared will then be displayed.)

It is similar to [sharing folders using a lan cable](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=13&info=Ubuntu_and_Gnome_Diary#crossover_lan_cable_network_linux).

Comment: how can i know what computer is what ip adress
192.168.1.1 is for modem options
i can open that page in firefox on both desktop and laptop

Comment: When you right-click a folder, there will be a "Sharing Options" menu. Select that. Are you on the network? Are you logged in as the main user?

Comment: If the modem at 192.168.1.1 is assigning IP addresses dynamically (modem is running its built-in DHCP server), then there may be a page at 192.168.1.1 where the IP addresses of other computers are listed. In Terminal, you can use the [ifconfig] command to obtain the IP address. In Windows, you can use [ipconfig /all].